# group by on dataframe pandas with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using python and I have a dataframe pandas :

```
unique_col | code | Col3 | ... | Col4
1          | A    | aa   | ... | aaa1  
2          | A    | bb   | ... | aaa2
3          | A    | cc   | ... | aaa3
4          | B    | dd   | ... | aaa4
5          | B    | ee   | ... | aaa5
6          | B    | ff   | ... | aaa6
```

I need to generate a dataframe which looks like this:
for each "code" i need to get the row that match with the max(unique_col)

```
unique_col | code | Col3 | ... | Col4
3          | A    | cc   | ... | aaa3
6          | B    | ff   | ... | aaa6
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Or, on the same assumption, df.groupby("code").last()
I don't know which is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby.last()` (or `.max()`, and make sure you sort your dataframe first with the column you want to get the max value of, i.e. `unique_col`:

```
df.sort_values(by=['unique_col']).groupby('code').last().reset_index()

  code  unique_col Col3  Col4
0    A           3   cc  aaa3
1    B           6   ff  aaa6
```

Answer (score 1):

if your max unique row will always come last, you can use the drop duplicate()

```
df.drop_duplicate(subset='code', keep= 'last', inplace= True)
```